# Javascript function return best practice / convention

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, conventions

Say I have this

```
if ( ! chargeCreditCard() ) {
    // my custom error message here.
    // would like to display 'err' from
    // chargeCreditCard
    render("Could not charge cc")
} else {
    render("thanks! will ship soon")
}

chargeCreditCard() {
    Library.charge(cc_info, function(err, success) {
        if (err)
            return false

         return true
     }
}
```

What is typically done if i would like to display "err" from `chargeCreditCard()` in the `if` statement ?

Since `chargeCreditCard` returns `true` or `false`, I just render to the server a basic "could not charge cc".

Should be doing  `return err` from inside `chargeCreditCard` and then do
something like

```
var result = chargeCreditCard
if ( result !== true) {
    render(result)
} else {
    render('thanks! will ship soon')
}
```

Not a coding question, but a data flow question i suppose.

Comment: i'd go with... neither. handle errors elsewhere, just generate an error message next it along to the router/app's error handler handle it like any other error, this also allows you to keep track of each occurrence in a centralized location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that makes more sense in this case, is returning a `Promise`. Promises are perfect tools to encapsulate asynchronous operations that may or may not succeed:

```
chargeCreditCard()
  .then(_ => render("thanks! will ship soon"))
  .catch(err => render(`Could not charge cc. Reason: ${err}`));

chargeCreditCard() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    Library.charge(cc_info, err => err ? reject(err) : resolve())
  );
}
```

Callback passing tends to make code over complicated, and even more when you begin chaining and nesting them. Sadly, promises are a relatively new tool and the vast majority of the NodeJS/Javascript opensource code heavily relies on callback passing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
function chargeCreditCard(callback) {
  Library.charge(cc_info, callback);
}

chargeCreditCard(function(err, success) {
  if (success) {
    render("thanks! will ship soon");

  } else {
    var errorMsg = "Could not charge cc.";

    if (err)
      errorMsg += " Error: " + err;

    render(errorMsg);
  }
});
```

Comment: The issue is, i do a few more things if the charge succeeded. like save customer data to database, send email, etc - and would like to keep those out of the `chargeCreditCard` function

Comment: In this case the chargeCreditCard function is only calling `Library.charge`.